# Creating a table from an old table using cells as column names in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a table, and I want to create a new table (from this table)

| Balance | Category | Sec_Master | Sec_Master_Comp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DATE | CATEGORY_ID (p.k.) | SEC_CODE | SEC_CODE |
| SEC_CODE | CAT_NAME | ISIN | COMPANY_NAME |
| COMP_CODE | DATE_V_F | DATE_V_F | DATE_V_F |
| CAT_ID | DATE_V_T | DATE_V_T | DATE_V_T |
| CURRENCY |  |  |  |
| DAILY_BALANCE |  |  |  |

From this table I want to create a new table such as the one below,

| DATE | CAT_NAME | SEC_CODE | ISIN | COMPANY_NAME | CURRENCY | DAIILY_BALANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

In SQLite, I tried using the following commands. I am able to generate a table with only one column like this,

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT balance
FROM table1 WHERE balance='currency'
```

But if I try to do multiple WHERE clause's it doesn't seem to work.

I tried to do:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT balance, category
FROM table1 WHERE balance='currency', category = 'date_valid_from'
```

I also tried using an AND statement but still no luck:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
SELECT balance, category
FROM table2 WHERE balance='currency' AND category = 'date_valid_from'
```

This just returns empty columns 'balance' and 'category' and not the specified Where clauses. i.e 'currency', 'date_valid_from'.

ALSO, the columns in the new tables, are the ones which I selected from the old table. i.e 'balance' and 'category' However I want the cells within those columns i.e 'currency' in 'balance' to be the new columns.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Sample data and desired results are present?  I'm not sure what you mean by tag

Comment: Yes, sure. It's SQlite, sorry.

Comment: That's a weird table... What does its columns mean? For example, why is a column called `balance` full of strings? I cannot make any sense out of that. I guess you need to elaborate quite a bit here to make that understandable...

Comment: It's a schema, from which you can make other tables according to your needs.